# android studio click button1 from activity1 to load activity2 webview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

My main goal is to click a button from `Activity1` and then `WebView` of `Activity2`  loads up a page from a html file locally.

Just for the test purpose I'll use only 1 button but personally I will have more then 1 button and each button will navigate to different page.

Here is the code I have in `Activity1` to open `Activity2`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

and this is what I want to load once `Activity2` loads

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                WebView view = new WebView(this);
                view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                setContentView(view);
```

I can do this with 1 button fine ?  but problem comes when i want to use a different button in `Activity1` with different page say index.html2 or index.html3. Can anyone help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: How is it possible to load .html2 or .html3??

Answer (score 1):

You should think about what is your problem.

You've got a button in Activity1.
Clicking the button starts Activity2 and doing some specific things (like opening index1.html) there.

Now you want to add some more buttons to Activity1.

Each button shall open Activity2, too. But each button shall do some specific things (like opening one out of "index1.html", "index2.html" or "index3.html").

So what's your problem?
You don't know how to tell Activity2 which Button was clicked, so **Activity2 doesn't know which "index.html" to open**.

**Now, let me tell you how to do it:**

You're using this code already to start Activity2:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

But an `Intent` can do much more than starting an `Activity`!
You can add data to the intent-object, and get them back later.

Add data to your intent by doing this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("htmlToOpen", "index1.html"); //Here you put your info
startActivity(intent);
```

Now, in your Activty2, you've got to get back the data:

```
String fileName = getIntent().getStringExtra("htmlToOpen");
```

Now you can use the String fileName to open your desired html-file:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
WebView view = new WebView(this);
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + fileName);
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
setContentView(view);
```

To learn more about `Intent`s read here: [Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

---

**By the way: I think you're trying to do the following:**

1. You start your app in your `MainActivity`.
2. There you've got a button. The user can click the button to open Activity1.
3. In Activity1 the user can choose one website (html-file).
4. The website should be shown in `MainActivity`, now.

**If this is what you want to do, let me suggest the Android-way to do it:**

In your `MainActivity`, you start Activity1 by doing this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

That code means you're starting your Activity1 just to get a result back (in this case, the result is the desired website).

Now, in your Activity1, you give the result (the desired website) back by doing this:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("htmlToOpen","index1.html"); //if another button was clicked, put another filename, here.
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

Now, back again in your `MainActivity`, you get the result by adding the following function:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == 1) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        String fileName = data.getStringExtra("htmlToOpen");
        //Now open your desired website by using the String fileName,
        //which contains the String "index1.html"
    }
}
}
```

If you want to learn more about starting Activities for results, read:

- [Starting Activities and Getting Results](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)
- [How to manage start activity for result on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result-on-android)

Comment: let me check it wow sir this looks good lemme try , am noob dont mind someone always starts of new right i appreciate your master guidence.

Comment: @user3695970 if you've got further questions (relating to my answer), ask here in the comments. If an answer is good to your question, you can mark it as "accepted answer", you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_1:
           Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.this);
            i.putExtra("page","file:///android_asset/index1.html");
            startActivity(i);

            break;
        case R.id.btn_2:
            Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.this);
            i.putExtra("page","file:///android_asset/index2.html");
            startActivity(i);

            break;
        case R.id.btn_3:
            Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.this);
            i.putExtra("page","file:///android_asset/index3.html");
            startActivity(i);

            break;
    }

}
```

and in your other activity `onCreate`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
String pageString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("page");
WebView view = new WebView(this);
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
view.loadUrl(pageString);
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
setContentView(view);`
```

Comment: when i send this command file:///android_asset/index1.html or this string  the activity2 page comes up but shows webpage unavailable showing this link file:///android_asset/index1.html  so is there a way to fix this as we know this isnt valid url but a path to the html in local